# fql multiquery error

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql, fql.multiquery

i have written following code to learn how fql multiquery works:

```
include_once "fbmain.php";
try{     
$your_id=xxxxxxxx;
     $fql= '{
     "friends":"SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1='.$your_uid.',"
     "friendinfo":"SELECT * FROM standard_user_info WHERE uid IN (SELECT uid2
                  FROM #friends)"
             }';
$res = $facebook->api_client->fql_multiquery($fql);   
   }
catch(Exception $o){
        d($o); // d() is function to print
    }
```

but the output shows error

**Call to a member function fql_multiquery() on a non-object on line 9**

i have also tried other queries instead of these two , but the problem remains same. i am using php sdk 3.0.

help pls.

Answer (score 0):

I do not use Multi Query, since fql has moved to the graph api.  Instead i use batch request.
Here is a sample of a request of /feed, the comments of the 1st 10 results and fql multi of the permalink from the 1st 10 posts.  I am sure this is a bit over kill for what you need but is the best example i have for mixing graph and fql and using name feature, which seems is what you need to carry friends.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/batch/

```
<?php 
    if($type=="home"){
$relURL = '/'.$pageid.'/'.$type.'?'.$access_token.'%26limit='.$limit.'%26return_ssl_resources=1%26fields=id,from,name,message,likes,comments,link,picture,caption,story,source,created_time,type,actions,application,object_id,description%26since='.$since.'%26until='.$until.'%26offset='.$offset.'';
    }else{
$relURL = '/'.$pageid.'/'.$type.'?'.$app_access_token.'%26limit='.$limit.'%26return_ssl_resources=1%26fields=id,from,name,message,likes,comments,link,picture,caption,story,source,created_time,type,actions,application,object_id,description%26since='.$since.'%26until='.$until.'%26offset='.$offset.'';
    }   
$queryProfile = array(
        array('method' => 'GET', 'relative_url' => '/'.$pageid.'?fields=id,name,link,picture%26'.$app_access_token.''),

    array('method' => 'GET', 'relative_url' => ''.$relURL.'', 'name' => 'comments', 'omit_response_on_success' => false),   
        array('method' => 'GET', 'relative_url' => '/{result=comments:$.data.0.id}/comments?fields=id,from,message,created_time%26limit=3%26offset=0'),
        array('method' => 'GET', 'relative_url' => '/{result=comments:$.data.1.id}/comments?fields=id,from,message,created_time%26limit=3%26offset=0'),
        array('method' => 'GET', 'relative_url' => '/{result=comments:$.data.2.id}/comments?fields=id,from,message,created_time%26limit=3%26offset=0'), 
        array('method' => 'GET', 'relative_url' => '/{result=comments:$.data.3.id}/comments?fields=id,from,message,created_time%26limit=3%26offset=0'), 
        array('method' => 'GET', 'relative_url' => '/{result=comments:$.data.4.id}/comments?fields=id,from,message,created_time%26limit=3%26offset=0'), 
        array('method' => 'GET', 'relative_url' => '/{result=comments:$.data.5.id}/comments?fields=id,from,message,created_time%26limit=3%26offset=0'), 
        array('method' => 'GET', 'relative_url' => '/{result=comments:$.data.6.id}/comments?fields=id,from,message,created_time%26limit=3%26offset=0'), 
        array('method' => 'GET', 'relative_url' => '/{result=comments:$.data.7.id}/comments?fields=id,from,message,created_time%26limit=3%26offset=0'),
        array('method' => 'GET', 'relative_url' => '/{result=comments:$.data.8.id}/comments?fields=id,from,message,created_time%26limit=3%26offset=0'),
        array('method' => 'GET', 'relative_url' => '/{result=comments:$.data.9.id}/comments?fields=id,from,message,created_time%26limit=3%26offset=0'),
        array('method' => 'GET', 'relative_url' => '/fql?q=SELECT+permalink+FROM+stream+WHERE+source_id=\''.$pageid.'\'+AND+post_id=\'{result=comments:$.data.0.id}\''),
        array('method' => 'GET', 'relative_url' => '/fql?q=SELECT+permalink+FROM+stream+WHERE+source_id=\''.$pageid.'\'+AND+post_id=\'{result=comments:$.data.1.id}\''),
        array('method' => 'GET', 'relative_url' => '/fql?q=SELECT+permalink+FROM+stream+WHERE+source_id=\''.$pageid.'\'+AND+post_id=\'{result=comments:$.data.2.id}\''),
        array('method' => 'GET', 'relative_url' => '/fql?q=SELECT+permalink+FROM+stream+WHERE+source_id=\''.$pageid.'\'+AND+post_id=\'{result=comments:$.data.3.id}\''),
        array('method' => 'GET', 'relative_url' => '/fql?q=SELECT+permalink+FROM+stream+WHERE+source_id=\''.$pageid.'\'+AND+post_id=\'{result=comments:$.data.4.id}\''),
        array('method' => 'GET', 'relative_url' => '/fql?q=SELECT+permalink+FROM+stream+WHERE+source_id=\''.$pageid.'\'+AND+post_id=\'{result=comments:$.data.5.id}\''),
        array('method' => 'GET', 'relative_url' => '/fql?q=SELECT+permalink+FROM+stream+WHERE+source_id=\''.$pageid.'\'+AND+post_id=\'{result=comments:$.data.6.id}\''),
        array('method' => 'GET', 'relative_url' => '/fql?q=SELECT+permalink+FROM+stream+WHERE+source_id=\''.$pageid.'\'+AND+post_id=\'{result=comments:$.data.7.id}\''),
    //array('method' => 'GET', 'relative_url' => '/'.$pageInfo[id].'/photos?fields=id,name%26limit=9')
);
$batchResponse = $facebook->api('?batch='.json_encode($queryProfile), 'POST');
    $pageInfo = json_decode($batchResponse[0]['body'], true);
    $pageType = $pageInfo[type];
    $pageLink = $pageInfo[link];
    $thispageid = $pageInfo[id];
    $MEcomments = json_decode($batchResponse[1]['body'], true);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks rather a problem with the instantiation of

```
$facebook->api_client
```

Worth to note also that in [standard_user_info] the column [uid] is of type *string* so you would probably also need to add quotes.
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/standard_user_info/

According to FB docs, FQL multiquery should be faster than subsequent batch calls.
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/